# How to center <i> tag in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to center an fa on a div using i tag but I'm kinda clueless on how to do that. Any help?

I'm kinda new here.

Thanks

Sample html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
    #lock-cirle {
        border: solid 2px #9f070a;
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
    }

    #lock-icon{
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #9f070a;
        margin: 27%;
    }


</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <div id="lock-cirle"  style="background-color: yellow;">
        <i class="fa fa-lock" id="lock-icon" style="background-color: green;"></i>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `text-align:center;` to the parent div `#lock-cirle`, like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
    #lock-cirle {
        border: solid 2px #9f070a;
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #lock-icon{
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #9f070a;
        margin: 27%;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <div id="lock-cirle"  style="background-color: yellow;">
        <i class="fa fa-lock" id="lock-icon" style="background-color: green;"></i>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Cuz `<I>` element is inline by default, and `text-align` CSS property describes how inline content is aligned

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: @iamcoder Cuz <I> element is inline by default, and text-align CSS property describes how inline content is aligned

Answer (score 2):

```
#lock-icon{
       font-size: 50px;
       color: #9f070a;
       margin: 27%;
       text-align: center;
    }
```

Correct your #lock-icon CSS as above since you want to center fa in the div.